# Как прописать в Linux путь для нахождения библиотеки в jar?

Tags: java, linux

Добрый день, запускаю готовый .jar на Linux но выскакивает ошибка

> java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql

для соединения с SQL использую mysql-connector-java-5.1.39-bin не понятно то что то что он подключён в проекте и в jar лежит и на windows работает.

```
/******************ПОДКЛЮЧАЕМСЯ К БАЗЕ ДАННЫХ*********************/
//JDBC URL, username and password of MySQL server

    private static final String url = "jdbc:mysql:";

    private static final String user = "";

    private static final String password = "";

    /**************************КОНЕЦ***************************/

  // --------ДОБАВЛЕНИЕ ДАННЫХ--------
                            try{

                                String query = "  INSERT INTO  coordinates_centre (id, la, lo\n"// добавляем данные в таблицу 
                                        +", ti, sp)\n"
                                            + "VALUES('"+id+"', '"+la+"', '"+lo+"', '"+ti+"', '"+sp+"');";

                                // opening database connection to MySQL server
                                con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);

                                // getting Statement object to execute query
                                stmt = con.createStatement();

                               // executing SELECT query
                                rs = stmt.executeUpdate(query);


                            } catch (SQLException sqlEx) {
                                sqlEx.printStackTrace();
                            } finally {
                                //close connection ,stmt and resultset here
                                try { con.close(); } catch(SQLException se) { /*can't do anything */ }
                                try { stmt.close(); } catch(SQLException se) { /*can't do anything */ }
                            }
                        // --------КОНЕЦ--------
```

Comment: Как запускаете на Windows и на Linux?

Comment: @Chubatiy на Windows из среды разработки на Linux командой java -jar myprogram.jar

Comment: в том то и беда. Получается что вы не "пакуете" библиотеки в ваш конечный jar. Чем собираете проект? Ant? Maven?

Comment: Ищите по теме `classpath`. В командной строке java как-то можно задать, с помощью переменной среды. Или jar с драйвером тоже перечисляется среди параметров в командной строке. А можно общие библиотеки покидать в специальную папку, не помню как называется.

Comment: @Chubatiy Eclipse но он лежи в архиве проверял.

Comment: java -cp jdbc-driver.jar -jar prog.jar

Comment: @Sergy с classpath пробовал разные варианты так же не работает.

Comment: параметр -cp(и  CLASSPATH) не работает вместе с параметром -jar

Comment: Воспользуйтесь maven или gradle или если вы ретроград, то ant. не нужно использовать jar архивы, явно прописывая пути к ним. Если же используемая библиотека не находится в репозитории то просто съимпортируете ее, или же пропишите в  pom.xml  (если это maven) пути до этой библиотеки.

Comment: @Chubatiy не работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант запуска через classpath, с указанием хранилища библиотек:

```
CLASSPATH=/home/chubatiy/my/<ИМЯ>.jar:/home/chubatiy/my/libs/ java org.me.Start
```

где:

1. /home/chubatiy/my/<ИМЯ>.jar полный путь к вашему JAR файлу
2. /home/chubatiy/my/libs/ путь к папке с библиотеками
3. org.me.Start полный путь к главному классу приложения

**UPD:** все оказалось проще. Не хватало строки регистрации драйвера. Т.е. необходимо добавить перед установкой соединения с БД:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

Comment: Самое странное что есть он в архиве и для надёжности ещё рядом .jar лежит пака lib с драйвером

Comment: Повторюсь. С помощью чего вы собираете? Ant? Maven? Приведите структуру выходного JAR(Если Ant) или pom.xml(если Maven)

Comment: средой разработки Eclipse драйвер лежит в паке lib при сборке в jar эта папка попадает в документе classpath адрес прописан начинается с lib

Comment: Главный класс я также указываю при сборке .jar

Comment: Вы пробовали запустить, как я указал в ответе? Все равно та же ошибка? Приведите пож. как вы в коде инициализируете подключение. Полностью всю строку подключения(можете убрать порт и прочее). Точно ли перед инициалищированием подключения вы вызываете `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")`?

Comment: 1)Да я пробовал как вы сказали. 
2)Так же выскакивает ошибка.
3) Как подключаюсь дополнил ответ 
а где нужно прописать Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver") я о нём в первые слышу ?

Comment: Вы привели параметры подключения. А сама строка подключения где собирается? Как вы инициализируете подключение? Как в коде вы используете данные параметры? С помощью каких классов вы подключаетесь к БД?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49959/discussion-between-varg-sieg-and-chubatiy).

Answer (score 2):

Аналог [ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/602487/181100) [@Chubatiy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/195819/chubatiy) через ключ `-cp` вместо переменной среды `CLASSPATH`:

```
java -cp "/home/chubatiy/my/<ИМЯ>.jar:/home/chubatiy/my/libs/" org.me.Start
```

`java -help` выводит, среди прочего, его синоним `-classpath` и описание этого ключа:

```
-cp <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
-classpath <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
              A : separated list of directories, JAR archives,
              and ZIP archives to search for class files.
```

Передать в нём нужно разделённые символом `:` пути к директориям и/или к отдельным JAR-ZIP-файлам, содержащим требуемые классы.